# How to add space between plotband and first bar(red color "A" bar) in highchart

Tags: highcharts

i have tried with following demo.
Demo  : https://jsfiddle.net/50tdn8hz/`enter code here`

Answer (score 0):

You can decrease `xAxis.min` value:

```
xAxis: {
  min: -1,
  ...
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/atryv6k5/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.min